# How to automatically sort on article id?

Tags: jquery, sorting

I'm trying to automatically sort with JQuery plugin TinySort ( http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/ ), but without success. I want to reverse the standard order: newest comments on top.
This is what I have:

```
<ol class="gui-blog-commentlist">
  <li>
    <article id="comment-53855">
      <header>
        <a href="#comment-53855">
          <time datetime="2014-05-19T15:46:31+02:00">19 May 2014 at 15:46</time>
        </a>
      </header>
      <p>First comment</p>
    </article>
  </li>
  <li>
    <article id="comment-53857">
      <header>
        <a href="#comment-53857">
          <time datetime="2014-05-20T15:48:57+02:00">20 May 2014 at 15:48</time>
        </a>
      </header>
      <p>Second comment</p>
    </article>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Then I use TinySort:

```
$('.gui-blog-commentlist > li').tsort('article', { order: 'desc', attr: 'id' });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help, it's my first question here.

Comment: Have you checked the console for any errors? Can you please describe why this does not work.

Comment: The console in your developer tools should throw something. If you get stuck with no errors in the console then you could take a look at [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) which I've been using with good results.

Comment: @Jonast92 how is that relevant to this question?

Comment: It looks like it has something to do with the `-` in the id... see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MR3T7/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you need to use the `forceStrings`

```
$('.gui-blog-commentlist > li').tsort('article', {
    order: 'desc',
    attr: 'id',
    forceStrings: true
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MR3T7/)